# How to create a temporary field on the fly via SQL and use that temporary field in an ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
date                   | raw_date
NULL                   | 01/01/2016
2016-09-13 13:00:00+00 | 01/02/2016
2016-09-13 13:00:00+00 | NULL
```

Is there a way to create a new temporary field: date_temp w/c uses the value of date if it is not null, and uses the value of raw_date if date is null and use the date_temp field in an ORDER BY clause. Using the example above, the result should be like this:

```
date_temp
2016-01-01 12:00:00+00
2016-09-13 13:00:00+00
2016-09-13 13:00:00+00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `COALESCE(date, to_date(raw_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'))`

I'm assuming your _raw_date_ column is just text/string data type.  You would need to cast it to a date first in order to use coalesce.  If you're going to get a bunch of variations of formatting in that column, you'll need to add additional logic.

REF: (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using DISTINCT in the query and it's throwing this error: `ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`. Any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Add it to your SELECT statement. Can you share the whole query and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT "event".* FROM "event" inner join team on team.id = event.team1_id OR team.id = event.team2_id inner join league on league.id = team.league_id WHERE (league.type ILIKE 'pro') AND (status in ('0','1','2')) ORDER BY COALESCE(date,raw_date::date) desc` , I modified it to: `SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(date,raw_date::date), "event".* FROM "event" inner join team on team.id = event.team1_id OR team.id = event.team2_id inner join league on league.id = team.league_id WHERE (league.type ILIKE 'pro') AND (status in ('0','1','2')) ORDER BY COALESCE(date,raw_date::date) desc` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) and [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
with my_table(date, raw_date) as (
values  
    (NULL::date, '01/01/2016'),
    ('2016-09-13 13:00:00+00', '01/02/2016'),
    ('2016-09-13 13:00:00+00', NULL)
)

select coalesce(date, to_date(raw_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) as date_temp
from my_table
order by 1;

 date_temp  
------------
 2016-01-01
 2016-09-13
 2016-09-13
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!